# How to go about getting into a Master’s in Economics program despite poor performance in undergrad?

Tags: masters, undergraduate, economics

I graduated recently with a BS in Economics. I am interested in pursuing my education in Economics but I realize that I am not adequately prepared as I did not perform well in my undergraduate coursework. I received As and Bs in my economic courses and ended with a GPA slightly below 3.5. I also did not have the opportunity to complete research so I understand that I do not have the major qualities a good program would be looking for. Any suggestions for what I can do to be accepted into a Master’s program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US you are probably acceptable, though maybe not in the top few institutions. The major GPA is more important than the overall one and "around" 3.5 isn't terrible in a lot of places.

You will need good letters of recommendation from some professors, probably in Econ, who know you well and will speak highly of you. Research prior to the MS is not a major concern in many programs either.

Outside the US it might be very different.